# Swift 4 Button fade in, out

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

how can I do fade in and out when button is pressed.

I am looking for most simple and best practice Swift 4 solution as possible.

Something like Apple iOS 11 Calculator button fade...

So far I have this...

```
myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
myButton.backgroundColor=UIColor.gray

myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
myButton.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
```

I am kinda lost. Many thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about fade in/out for calculator but you will get similar effect by this:

Set UIButton type as Custom and set Text Color as White from storyboard.

[image]

Set BackgroundColor of UIButton as Tungsten(take e.g. Calculator app)

[image]

Create custom class for UIButton and **set customButton class to UIButton from Identity Inspector**.

```
class customButton: UIButton {
    override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            //Set colors for Highlighted & Unhighlighted
            backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.7) : UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]